# Grouping the contents of a combobox and adding titles - c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have linked my combobox to a list but I would like the combobox to have gaps and titles that the user cannot click on. The procedure I have used to populate the combobox automatically  takes the contents of the list. I have not used the method where you simply manually type the contents of the combobox. Here is my code:

```
class Appliances
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public double energy_rating { get; set;}
        public Appliances(String nameInput, double energy_ratingInput)
        {
            name = nameInput;
            energy_rating = energy_ratingInput;
        }
    }

List<Appliances> appliancesList = new List<Appliances>      
        {
            new Appliances("Freezer",0.15),
            new Appliances("Fridge",0.08),
            new Appliances("Fridge-freezer",0.3),
            new Appliances("Grill/hob",1.5),
            new Appliances("Kettle",2.6),
            new Appliances("Microwave",1),
            new Appliances("Oven",2.1),
            new Appliances("Toaster",1.1),
            new Appliances("Dishwasher",1.3),
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a ComboBox supports groups and separators. You might take a look at http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/104